# How to search the shortest distance between a set of nodes using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to figure out if there's someway using cypher in Neo4j to get the shortest distance between a group of nodes.

Some notes to take account for this search:
 - Distance is a property of the relationships between nodes. Distance values are in meters
 - All nodes have a relationship between them with a given distance.
 - The start and end nodes to follow must be the same node.

This is what kind of input i want:

```
MATCH
(root) -[root_p1:PATH_TO]-> (p1), (root) -[root_p2:PATH_TO]-> (p2), (root) -[root_p3:PATH_TO]-> (p3), (p1) -[p1_root:PATH_TO]-> (root), (p1) -[p1_p2:PATH_TO]-> (p2), (p1) -[p1_p3:PATH_TO]-> (p3), (p2) -[p2_root:PATH_TO]-> (root), (p2) -[p2_p1:PATH_TO]-> (p1), (p2) -[p2_p3:PATH_TO]-> (p3), (p3) -[p3_root:PATH_TO]-> (root), (p3) -[p3_p1:PATH_TO]-> (p1), (p3) -[p3_p2:PATH_TO]-> (p2)
WHERE ID(root) = 10 AND ID(p1) = 1 AND ID(p2) = 2 AND ID(p3) = 3
.
.
.
```

And then the result should be correct sequence of nodes that contribute to get the shortest path possible.

Comment: It is not clear what should be on output. It would be better if you bring an example of input data and the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

This query might suit you needs:

```
MATCH p=(n)-[rels:PATH_TO*]->(n)
WITH p, REDUCE(s = 0, x IN rels | s + x.distance) AS dist
WITH p, MIN(dist) AS d
ORDER BY d
LIMIT 1
RETURN RELATIONSHIPS(p), d;
```

It finds all directed cyclic paths with `PATH_TO` relationships; calculates the total distance of each path; gets one path (out of potentially many) with the shortest total distance; and returns all of its relationships, along with the total distance.

*Note: This query can take a very long time for large graphs. If so, you can try to put a reasonable upper bound on  the variable-length pattern. For example, replace `[rels:PATH_TO*]` with `[rels:PATH_TO*..5]`.*